# Array of ui-bootstrap typeaheads not in sync with underlying array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am encountering a synchronization issue when trying to use a UI-Bootstrap typeahead inside an ng-repeat block.  The issue comes up when my typeahead is being rendered by another directive.

Basically, I am trying to create a dynamic array of typeaheads in a form.  The user can add and remove typeaheads at will.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
<h4>Array of typeaheads</h4>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  <ng-form>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <autocomplete ng-model="items[$index]" options="options" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <button type="button" ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="btn btn-danger">
        Remove Item
      </button>
    </div>
  </ng-form>

</div>
<button type="button" ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-primary">
  Add Item
</button>
<pre>{{items}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('autocomplete', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      options: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      if ($scope.ngModel) {
        $scope.ngModelName = $scope.ngModel.name;
      }

      $scope.onSelect = function($item, $model, $label) {
        $scope.ngModel = $item;
        $scope.ngModelName = $item.name;
      };
    },
    template: '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ngModelName" typeahead="o.name for o in options | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" />'

  };
});
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.options = [{
    name: 'Alabama',
    type: 'A'
  }, {
    name: 'Alaska',
    type: 'B'
  }, {
    name: 'Arizona',
    type: 'C'
  }, ];
  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push({});
  };

  $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  };

});
```

Here's a Plunkr that demonstrates the issue:  http://plnkr.co/edit/lugLKkgp8GkUf2Kjdewg?p=preview

Basically, adding additional typeaheads works fine.  Let's say I add three typeaheads and select an input for all of them.  My state becomes:

[image: Initial (good) state]

But now, if I try to remove the second typeahead (the one that has "Alaska" selected), my underlying state gets updated properly (the `items` array just has Alabama and Arizona selected) but the UI shows Alabama and Alaska.

[image: Bad state after the removal of the middle item]

It's as if whenever I remove an item, the underlying state is updated correctly but the UI always removes the last item in the list.

Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

**Note**: I have good reasons for wrapping the typeahead in my own directive, but I just showed a reduced version so this question could have an MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
```

Since you do `track by $index` - you don't assign to your model some unique value, you just reference to the array item by it's id.

So, for example, you have just 2 `typeahead`s. The first's model is `items[0]`, the second's is `items[1]`. When you delete the first - reference stays, but model itself is removed. If you will make some changes - everythig will be rendered good, because you still have 1 element in `items` array, but it's already another model.

Resolve of problem - just remove `track by $index`. Then everything will work perfectly until you will choose 2 the same values.

For more info take a look at [`ngRepeat` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

You will see here:

**`item in items`**`is equivalent to`**`item in items track by $id(item)`**`. This implies that the DOM elements will be associated by item identity in the array.`
**`item in items track by $id(item)`**`. A built in` **`$id()`**`function can be used to assign a unique`**`$$hashKey`** `property to each item in the array. This property is then used as a key to associated DOM elements with the corresponding item in the array by identity. Moving the same object in array would move the DOM element in the same way in the DOM.`

#### Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdNdb1KkR7s6lOqE9rwq?p=preview

### Update

If you want everything working with the same values - you just need to add some additional field to your items, like this:

```
  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push({random: +new Date()});
  };
```

So now your `item`s will be different, that's why you would not need to add `track by` in your `ng-repeat`.

But now you have one more problem: when you choose some value from `typeahead` - this value is changed. That's why you need to do next thing:

```
  $scope.onSelect = function($item, $model, $label) {
    angular.extend($scope.ngModel, $item);
    $scope.ngModelName = $item.name;
  };
```

Now every time you will choose some value from `typeahead` everything will work perfectly.

#### Updated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdNdb1KkR7s6lOqE9rwq?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your response!  The reason I was doing "track by $index" was to allow duplicates in the array.  Is there an idiomatic way to do this that doesn't encounter this problem?  I'm thinking I might have to add a unique key to each item and track by that instead.

Comment: @JoshuaBarron: I updated my answer. Now you could to choose same values